# Slow query to count tags

Tags: mysql

This query counts videos in relation to tags (top 50). It runs very slow (video table around 800k records). I have set all the appropriate indexes/keys.

```
SELECT `tags`.`id_tag`, `tags`.`tag_text`, COUNT(video_tags`.`id_video`) AS `total_video_count`
FROM `tags`
  INNER JOIN `video_tags` ON ( `tags`.`id_tag` = `video_tags`.`id_tag` )
  INNER JOIN `videos` ON ( `video_tags`.`id_video` = `videos`.`id_video` )
GROUP BY `tags`.`id_tag`
ORDER BY  `total_video_count` DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Any ideas of what could be contributing to the poor performance or any alternative ways to structure query?

----Update ----

```
+--------+------------+------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name                                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| videos |          0 | PRIMARY                                  |            1 | id_video        | A         |      812967 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

+------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name                                                | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| video_tags |          0 | PRIMARY                                                 |            1 | id_video_tag | A         |     4113266 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| video_tags |          1 | video_tags_id_tag_7e0eba6ebf2ab1be_fk_tags_id_tag       |            1 | id_tag       | A         |       10852 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| video_tags |          1 | video_tags_id_video_6fa83a06b3a6ec45_fk_videos_id_video |            1 | id_video     | A         |     1371088 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tags  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id_tag      | A         |       35186 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tags  |          0 | tag_text |            1 | tag_text    | A         |       35186 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Show table strtuctures/indexes/result of EXPLAIN or just buy bigger box.

Comment: Show indexes so we can be sure that you made them properly.

Comment: Added indexes to original description.

Comment: Could there be a composite unique key on video_tags (id_tag, id_video)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above last comment is correct ..

add an index on video_tags (id_tag, id_video).  What should happen is the first left join should kick that new index into action. and it will pull the id_video into memory and get the second left join predicate in memory..

What I believe is happening is that you are making another read to the video_tags table to pull in the id_video column.. so thats a non mem hit to the table.. then if the physical layout of the rows in video_tags does not match the sequence of the PRIMARY KEY (What its probably using).. You end up thrashing IO

I would try adding the composite key composite unique key on video_tags (id_tag, id_video) and give it another shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    `tags`.`id_tag`, 
    `tags`.`tag_text`,
    `ranking`.`total_video_count` as `total_video_count`
FROM tags
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        `video_tags`.`id_tag`,
        count(*) as total_video_count
    FROM `video_tags`
    GROUP BY `video_tags`.`id_tag`
    ORDER BY  `total_video_count` DESC
    LIMIT 50
) ranking ON ( `tags`.`id_tag` = `ranking`.`id_tag` )
```

There could be some possible typos. Anyway, you get the basic idea. It should increase performance in case you were joining two large tables.